# Google Sheets Conditional formatting custom formula: if current cell is empty, but other cell is not

Tags: google-sheets

So I'm trying to write a custom formula in google sheets for this condition. I want the current cell to be blacked out if it's empty, but only if this other cell is not empty. This prevents a lot of other cells from being blacked out further down the column (I'm adding new rows periodically as new data becomes available).

I can do something like =E:E<>"", which tests if the other cell is not empty, but I can't figure out how to add to it to test that the current cell is empty.

I want to test that column F is empty, and that column E is not. The row number would be the same, ie F1 is empty, E1 is not empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=AND(ISBlank(E1),NOT(isBlank(F1)))
```

Entered in E1

Apply to E1:E