# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting: if cell A is full, and this cell is empty

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

These should have been enough, but none of them have worked nor do any of their descriptions give an understanding of how they are supposed to work.

- [Google Sheets Conditional formatting custom formula: if current cell is empty, but other cell is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513419/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-custom-formula-if-current-cell-is-empty-b)
- [Google Spreadsheet conditional formatting based on empty cell with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899166/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-empty-cell-with-spaces)
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85245/apply-conditional-formatting-if-other-cell-is-not-empty
- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en

Here's the logic in code form:

```
const row = ["Some Name", "A value", null, null, "Another Value"];

function conditionMet(row: string[], column: index) {
  return row[0] && !row[column]
}
```

Here's how I think it should be formatted:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A)), ISBLANK(THIS))
```

Here's my best translation of the above based off the examples I've seen:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A:1)), ISBLANK(A:1))
```

This isn't working.  I can't seem to find a "THIS" argument.  I also don't understand why every example includes a row number.  There's a fundamental gap in knowledge here that I'm sure is very obvious once you know it, but I haven't seen it specified yet.

Edit: example included

```css
td {
 border: solid black;
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}

td[r] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>C</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td r></td>
  <td>C</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td r></td>
  <td r></td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>B</td>
  <td r></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet with your expected output. Are you trying to check if a particular column is not empty, while the other column is empty? It seems to be a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I can't envision your data layout given your post description. But for starters, cells are referenced as `A1` (etc.) not `A:1`. Colons are used to show the upper-left and bottom-right cells in a range (e.g., `A2:B5`). I concur with "Ron M"—sharing a link to a sample sheet will be best for clarity and efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't need to apply this conditional formatting on Column A, you can use the following formula to apply the conditional formatting for Range B:C

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A1)), ISBLANK(B1))
```

There is no "THIS" keyword specifically for conditional formatting, but it depends on the range that you're applying the formula to.

If you apply the above formula for `B1:C10`, then it will work like the "THIS" keyword because the 2nd `ISBLANK(B1)` doesn't have a `$`.If you apply it to any other range, it won't work the same.

So, you can use the very first cell address of your conditional-formatting range to indicate the "THIS" keyword

And you can actually simplify the above formula like this:

```
=AND($A1<>"",B1="")
```

You can see it in action in below screenshot:

[image: Conditional Formatting with current cell]

Comment: If the range were A1:C7, would that make "A1" equivalent to "this"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score -1):

try on range X1:X:

```
=NOT(ISBLANK($A1))*ISBLANK($X1)
```

where X is your column